# How to send/receive Bitcoins from cold wallet?

Tags: wallet, offline

I have generated a Cold Wallet using `bitaddress.org` (pub + priv key)

How do I send / receive Bitcoins from / to the generated addresses?
Is there something I should mind about?
Receiving seems to be easy: Just send Bitcoins to the generated Bitcoin Address, correct?

I have no problem to use the commandline.

Is there a way to do this (send / receive) without needing to use my private key on a computer connected to the internet?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there a way to do this (send / receive) without needing to use my private key on a computer connected to the internet?"

Yes, search for 'offline wallet'. The basic idea is the following:

- download the 'offline wallet' webpage you liked
- you must be online to fill blanks like addresses, amount and fee
- sign the transaction while offline and copy it
- go to a website that broadcast transactions
- paste your raw transaction already signed and push it

In my opinion, this is the safest way for non-developers to do bitcoin transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a watch-only address for your "online created cold address" (which you probably can read-out the irony in my sentence).

`bitcoin-cli importaddress <myaddress>`
(this will produce a rescan and take therefore some minutes/hours)

After that, you can check your balance as you would do with a "normal" addresses.

To spend, you could use the `rawtransaction` command (it's a bit tricky, see [here](http://blog.macoymejia.com/2014/08/15/bitcoin-raw-transaction-made-easy/)). With `signrawtransaction` you can use a private key (in the format you have created it over bitaddress.org) to sign your transaction.